# Simplifying 4 NAND Gates Into 1 XOR Gate Boolean Algebra?

Tags: boolean, xor, boolean-logic

I am trying to understand with boolean algebra how using 4 NAND Gates can be equivalen to 1 XOR gate.

If we look at this picture from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate#Alternatives

There is a schematic of the gate.

This is the large expression I came up with to express the schematic. Perhaps it is wrong and that may be my issue? But still I cannot see how to transform the equation into the XOR expression I expect.

I have: `!X!Y + X(!X!Y) + Y(!X!Y) + XY(!X!Y)`

I know XOR logic looks like this:  `X!Y + !XY`.

Can anyone clear up my confusion?

Comment: Your input does not look correct to me. How did you come up with that - can you show the steps you took from the wiki drawing to your function?

Comment: Okay where did the ors come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation of the schematic on Wikipedia is a little bit off. I translated it into

```
!(!(A!(AB))!(B!(AB)))
```

Notice that !(XY) and !X!Y are different and that the schematic does not have any or gates (so no `+` operators). From there we can simplify using various boolean logic:

```
(!(!(A!(AB))) + !(!(B!(AB))))
(A!(AB) + B!(AB))
(A(!A + !B) + B(!A + !B))
(A!B + B!A)
```